# How can I find the position of the first alpha [A-Za-z] in a string?

Tags: php, regex, string, substring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find the index of a regex match in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465027/how-do-i-find-the-index-of-a-regex-match-in-a-string)
>   [How to get the position of a Regex match in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571231/how-to-get-the-position-of-a-regex-match-in-a-string)

Given the following strings, how can I find the position of the first alpha in each string?

1) `- Alpha`

2) `beta`

3) `. Gamma`

4) `'delta'`

Ultimately I'm after the substring, starting at the first alpha character.  So I'm looking to offset my substring to get `Alpha`.

The offsets I'm looking for (from the above examples) are:

1) 2

2) 0

3) 2

4) 1

I'm not concerned with any special characters.  Just the first alpha, case insensitive (A-Za-z).

Comment: I'm not sure where to go for this.  Ultimately I will be using: `substring($str,$offset);` But I'm not sure how to clean my data to get the right offset.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9571252/1114536

Comment: @Rajat: Just flag it as a duplicate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [preg_match()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) :

### Code:

```
foreach (array('- Alpha', 'beta', '. Gamma', "'delta'") as $value) {
    preg_match('~[a-z]~i', $value, $match, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
    print_r($match);
}
```

### Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => A
            [1] => 2
        )
)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => b
            [1] => 0
        )
)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => G
            [1] => 2
        )
)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => d
            [1] => 1
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop and add if condition inside,Run the for loop across entire string and 'i' is the character at the current position

```
if(i>='a' && i<='z' || i>='A' && i<='Z')
```