# How to explode string by selected html tags

Tags: php, dom, explode

I need to explode string, which contains (not valid) HTML, by selected tags - `<p>, <ol>, <ul>, <table>, <h1-6>` . If any tags are nested, string should be exploded only by first one.

Inserted input:

```
  <div id="main">
  <h1 id="heading">Heading h1</h1>
  <p>
  <ol>
    <li>abc</li>
    <li>def</li>
    <li>ghi</li>
  </ol>
  Lorem ipusm lorem ipsum Lorem ipusm lorem ipsum Lorem ipusm lorem ipsum Lorem ipusm.
  </p>
  <p>Test test test test test</p>
  <ul>
    <li>aaa</li>
  </ul>
  </div>
```

Exptected output:

```
$output[0] = '<div id="wrapp"><h1 id="heading">Heading h1</h1>';
$output[1] = '<p><ol><li>abc</li><li>def</li><li>ghi</li></ol>Lorem ipusm lorem ipsum Lorem ipusm lorem ipsum Lorem ipusm lorem ipsum Lorem ipusm.</p>';
$output[2] = '<p>Test test test test test</p>';
$output[3] = '<ul><li>aaa</li></ul></div>';
```

I have tried a few DOM libraries, but no one can not what I need. The biggest problem is split div#main element and nested tags (not valid html). I appreciate any ideas.

Comment: What's the purpose of this? What ever it is, it can be done with DOMDocument. XY Problem?

Comment: I need to explode long string to shorter pieces because of translation into different languages (the whole idea is little bit complicated).I've tried for example Ganon library and its problem is at <div><p><ol></ol></p></div> part. Ganon returns me <div> -> <p> and <div> -> <ol>, which is wrong - it should be <div> -> <p> -> <ol> .

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex like `<(p|h[1-6]|ul|ol|table)` with preg_match to [find the position of your opening tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571231/how-to-get-the-position-of-a-regex-match-in-a-string). Then use the match that is returned to find the closing match.
Your code would look something like this

```
$html = "<div id="wrapp"><h1 id="heading">Heading ...";
$output = $match = array();
$regex = '<(p|h[1-6]|ul|ol|table)';
while(preg_match($regex, $html, $match, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)){
    $endTag = '</' . $match[1][0] '>';
    $endPosition = strpos($html, $endTag)
    $output[] = substr($html, 0 , $endPosition);
    $html = substr($html, $endPosition + strlen($endTag));
}
```

Note that this code is untested.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed a few bugs, but basically it works how I need. I just worry about its speed, when very large string comes in.

This is runnable version:
$output = $match = array();
$regex = '/<(p|h[1-6]|ul|ol|table)/';
while(preg_match($regex, $html, $match, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
    $endTag = '</' . $match[1][0] . '>';
    $endPosition = strpos($html, $endTag);
    $output[] = htmlspecialchars(substr($html, 0 , $endPosition + strlen($endTag)));
    $html = substr($html, $endPosition + strlen($endTag));
}
$output[] = htmlspecialchars(substr($html, 0, strlen($html)));
print_r($output);